# ASP.NET MVC mandatory argument for controller attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Is there a way to create an ASP.NET MVC attribute with a mandatory argument ?

```
[MyPersonalAttribut(MyMandatoryValue="....")]
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View();
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to have a non nullable parameter for the Index Method

```
   public ActionResult Index(int id)
   { 
     return View();
   }
```

would require a valid int to navigate there

Comment: I know but I'd like an attribute

Comment: @Kris-I *Why* do you want an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

**Action filter**

```
public class MandatoryAttribute: FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    private readonly string _requiredField;

    public MandatoryAttribute(string requiredField)
    {
        _requiredField = requiredField;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var val = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(_requiredField);

        if (val == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(val.AttemptedValue))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} is missing"),
                            _requiredField);
    }
}
```

**Action**

```
[Mandatory("param")]
public ActionResult MyTest()
{
  return Content("OK");
}
```

Comment: Yes but it's at running time. I'd like at compilation time.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by compilation time?

Comment: I place the attribute on the top of the action, if the mandatory argument is not present, I receive a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by having only one constructor in the Attribute that takes one argument. Like this:

```
public class MyPersonalAttribute : Attribute
{
    public object MyMandatoryValue { get; private set; }

    // The only constructor in the class that takes one argument...
    public MyPersonalAttribute(object value)
    {
        this.MyMandatoryValue = value;
    }
}
```

Then, if you'll get a receive a compilation error if you do not provide the argument when using the Attribute like below:

This will work:

```
[MyPersonalAttribute("some value")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

This will give you a compilation error:

```
[MyPersonalAttribute()]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```